# Question on matrices inverses

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb C)$ and $B\in M_{n\times m}(\mathbb C)$ be two matrices. If $AB$ is invertible, does it mean that $A$ and $B$  are invertible? If so, then how do I prove that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define the inverse of a  $m×n$ matrix if $m\neq n$?

Comment: To clarify, my question was not meant to be offending in any way. Rather: Do you also think about [pseudo inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore–Penrose_inverse) in your question.

Comment: No, $A$ and $B$ will not be invertible in general but you can prove that $A$ has right inverse and $B$ has left inverse.

Answer (score 3):

No.

To be invertible, a matrix has to be a square matrix which is not the case here.

If they are indeed square matrices, note that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. Try to prove it using this identity.

Comment: Is there a solvation without using determinants? *we've just started this chapter*

Comment: If $(AB)C = I$, then $A(BC)=I$, try to prove $B$ is invertible too for the context of square matrix.